# Change HTML select variable in Python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am using selenium in python and would like to change the value of the select. I want to pass, let's say, value of 500, which is not part of the select. How can I do that?

```
<select name="Table_len" aria-controls="Table_leg2" class="" data-role="none">
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="100">100</option>
    </select>
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use 
`browser.execute_script()`
with Javascript similar to this:

```
document.getElementById("Table_leg2").options[0].setAttribute("value", "500")
```